# javascript switch statement, if string contains substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to do a switch statement where I need to find a class name of the object, then do something depending on the class name (in the switch statement).

In this example, I need the switch statement to do whatever I need when the class contains a specific word, such as "person".

html

```
<div class="person temp something"></div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    var clicked = $(e.target).attr('class');
    console.log(clicked);
    switch (clicked) {
        case "person":
            //do something
            break;
        default:    
            //do something  
    }
});
```

It's not guaranteed that the switch statement name, such as "person" will be in the first spot.

I know I can search through an array for a specific word, but I don't know how to add that to this sort of thing.

Comment: It sounds like a `switch` statement is not the appropriate approach for this problem. It uses strict comparison to compare the input value to each `case` value. Use an `if` statement instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in my comment, a `switch` statement doesn't appear the appropriate approach in this situation.

Since you are using jQuery, just use [**`.hasClass`**](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/):

```
if ($(e.target).hasClass('person')) {
  // do something
}
```

If you want to do something more complicated for multiple classes, you can create a `class -> function` mapping and simply iterate over the class list:

```
var classActions = {
    person: function(element) { /* do something */ },
    temp: function(element) { /* do something */},
    // ...
};

var classes = e.target.className.split(/\s+/);
$.each(classes, function(index, cls) {
    classActions[cls](e.target);
});
```

Comment: I was afraid of that!  Thank you, I like your method of checking for all of the classes, I could use this in the future nicely.

Comment: Quick question, does the `classActions` variable have to be within the function that's calling it?

Comment: This is the best answer because it avoids `.split()` and `.search()` the way they are used in the other answers: this way is much cleaner.

Comment: @ntgCleaner: Nope, it can be defined outside. You'd just have to pass all the dependencies/values the functions need to them (e.g. the event target).

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting a `undefined is not a function` error and I've declared the `classActions` variable globally.  Any thoughts?

Comment: it seems `classActions[cls](e.target)` isn't actually outputting `classActions.person(e.target)`.  If I put this in manually, it works, but it's not handling the shorthand.

Comment: @ntgCleaner: Oh `$.each` passes the index as first argument and the values as second argument... updating.

Comment: Ah yes, that's working now.  Now I need to figure out how to deal with when there's no function for the random class names that may be there.  Thank you for the update!

Comment: @ntgCleaner: A one-liner would be `classActions[cls] && classActions[cls](e.target);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59441/discussion-between-ntgcleaner-and-felix-kling).

Comment: I implemented your one liner and it's working perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use a combination of **.split()** and **.indexOf()**.  Your code would be something like this:

```
var clicked = $(e.target).attr('class');
var classes = clicked.split(' ');

    if(classess.indexOf('person') > 0) {
      //do work
    } else if (classes.indexOf('foo') > 0) {
      //do work
    } else if (classes.indexOf('bar') > 0) {
      //do work
    }
```

MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on .split()

MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on .indexOf()

Comment: shouldn't he check against `-1`, because it's **zero-based** ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are plenty of methods that allow you to do this. For example you can use `string.search(substring)` to check if a string contains your substring. If there is a substring it returns the index it was found (some number from **0 to n**), otherwise if it's not found it returns -1. So if the `search` is larger or equal to 0, the  substring exist.

```
if(clicked.search("person") >= 0)
    // "person" is in clicked
```